# Array variable scope from IF / else statement

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, variables, advanced-custom-fields

Version A updates the post correctly, but version B fails.

Version A contains wp_update_post within each IF / ELSE statement. Version B has wp_update_post at the end, outside of the IF / ELSE statement.

Is this expected behaviour?

**Version A**

```
if ( $letter == 'A' ) {
    $my_post = array(
        'ID' => $post_id,
        'post_title' => 'A Title',
        'post_name' => $post_id
    );

    wp_update_post( $my_post );
} elseif ( $letter == 'B' ) {
    $name_field = $_POST['acf'][field_55749b0918a33]; // Name
    $my_post = array(
        'ID' => $post_id,
        'post_title' => 'B Title',
        'post_name' => $post_id
    );

    wp_update_post( $my_post );
} elseif ( $letter == 'C' ) {
    $my_post = array(
        'ID' => $post_id,
        'post_title' => 'C Title',
        'post_name' => $post_id
    );

    wp_update_post( $my_post );
}
```

**Version B**

```
if ( $letter == 'A' ) {
    $my_post = array(
        'ID' => $post_id,
        'post_title' => 'A Title',
        'post_name' => $post_id
    );
} elseif ( $letter == 'B' ) {
    $my_post = array(
        'ID' => $post_id,
        'post_title' => 'B Title',
        'post_name' => $post_id
    );
} elseif ( $letter == 'C' ) {
    $my_post = array(
        'ID' => $post_id,
        'post_title' => 'C Title',
        'post_name' => $post_id
    );
}

wp_update_post( $my_post );
```

Comment: Please elaborate on *Version B fails*...

Comment: So, what's the problem?  What do you expect to happen?  What does happen?  Do you see any errors?  P.S. What would happen if `$letter` happened to be `'D'`?

Comment: I've updated the question and included some full 'un-simplified' code for reference. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a scope problem, if you use the variable outside if construction you should declare it outside too,

```
$my_post = array(
        'ID' => 0
        'post_title' => '',
        'post_name' => ''
    );
if ( $letter == 'A' ) {
    $my_post = array(
        'ID' => $post_id,
        'post_title' => 'A Title',
        'post_name' => $post_id
    );
} elseif ( $letter == 'B' ) {
    $my_post = array(
        'ID' => $post_id,
        'post_title' => 'B Title',
        'post_name' => $post_id
    );
} elseif ( $letter == 'C' ) {
    $my_post = array(
        'ID' => $post_id,
        'post_title' => 'C Title',
        'post_name' => $post_id
    );
}

wp_update_post( $my_post );
```

or better:

```
$my_post = array(
        'ID' => $post_id,
        'post_title' => '',
        'post_name' => $post_id
    );
switch($letter){
case 'A':
case 'B':
case 'C':
    $my_post['post_title'] = $letter . " Title"
break;
default:
break;
}
wp_update_post( $my_post );
```

Answer (score 2):

For whatever reason, I think your function is being called twice. In Version B, if your function is called but `$letter` is undefined or does not match any of your `if` conditions, then `wp_update_post( $my_post );` will be called, and `$mypost` will be undefined.

To test this, try running Version B, and creating another version of your array *outside* of your `if` blocks. If this ends up appearing in your output, then you know the function is being called twice somehow.

Answer (score 1):

In the version A the function wp_update_post() start if $letter ='a' or 'b' or 'c' but not 'd', in the version B this function start $letter='a-z'